# creating new element with click-function do not work (cant set focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I create a new element with jquery and add a click function like above, the click-function do not work certain.

I would like to set focus on the eqivalent element but it focus only the last one.

To better explain I made a jsfiddel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZXL/2/)

```
          var newUL = $('<ul />',{
                        text: "ul text",
                        'class': 'errorListUl'
                      });

          for ( var i = 0; errorList[i]; i++ ) {
              var el = errorList[i];           console.log("element: ",el.element);
              $( "<li/>", {
                "class": "errorListLi",
                html: "<span>"+errorList[i].element.name+"</span><span>"+errorList[i].method+"</span>"+errorList[i].message,
                click: function() {
                    $(el.element).focus();  console.log("go to: ",$(el.element));
                }
              }).appendTo(newUL);
          }
          newUL.appendTo( $('#response') );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop finishes before your element is inserted into dom. Due to this fact, it will add handlers only on the last element. You need an anonymous function (closure) to handle this issue. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZXL/6/).

```
var newUL = $('<ul />',{
            html: "Click on error-message (li) shout focus the equivalent element. But the focus is always set to the last element.<br><br>",
            'class': 'errorListUl'
          });

for ( var i = 0; errorList[i]; i++ ) {
    (function(_i) {
        var el = errorList[_i],
            htmlText = "<span>" + el.element.name + "</span><span>" + el.method + "</span>" + el.message;

        console.log("element: ", el.element);

        $( "<li/>", {
            "class": "errorListLi",
            html: htmlText,
            click: function() {
                $(el.element).focus();  console.log("go to: ",$(el.element));
            }
    }).appendTo(newUL);
    })(i)
}

newUL.appendTo( $('#response') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of closure: this [link](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure) will explain better than me :)

check my modifications on [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UZXL/3/)

```
var errorList = [];

var check =  function( element ) {    
    errorList.push({
                    message: "text-message",
                    element: element,
                    method: "text-method"
                });
}

$(document).find("input, select, textarea").each(function(i, item) {
                   var checked = check(item);
});
console.log(errorList);

              var newUL = $('<ul />',{
                            html: "Click on error-message (li) shout focus the equivalent element. But the focus is always set to the last element.<br><br>",
                            'class': 'errorListUl'
                          });

              for ( var i = 0; errorList[i]; i++ ) {
                  var _item = errorList[i];
                  (function (item) {
                  $( "<li/>", {
                    "class": "errorListLi",
                    html: "<span>"+item.element.name+"</span><span>"+item.method+"</span>"+item.message,
                    click: function() {
                        $(item.element).focus();
                    }
                  }).appendTo(newUL);

                  })(_item)
              }
              newUL.appendTo( $('#response') );
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the el variable in the click handler, which is defined in the outer closure and which will change to be the last of the list, when the for loop has completed. If you want to change the behaviour to be correct, you must write the loop as:

```
      for ( var i = 0; errorList[i]; i++ ) {
          var el = errorList[i];
          console.log("element: ",el.element);
          (function (el2) {
              $( "<li/>", {
                "class": "errorListLi",
                html: "<span>"+errorList[i].element.name+"</span><span>"+errorList[i].method+"</span>"+errorList[i].message,
                click: function() {
                    $(el2.element).focus();
                    console.log("go to: ",$(el2.element));
                }
              }).appendTo(newUL);
          })(el);
      }
```

This way, you will create a new variable el2, which will not change over the loop, since it is copied to the instantly invoking function body.